# Shell script returning "Running: command not found". Not sure why

Tags: bash, shell, variable

When I am setting a variable to a command, I am getting the answer along with the error "command not found". Below is the command in the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

fs=$(ps -C "daemon_name" > /dev/null && echo "Running" || echo "Not Running")

$fs
```

Output:

```
./test.sh: Line 5: Running: command not found
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ps` is finding the process you are looking for which causes your `fs` variable to be set to `Running`.  When you call `$fs` you are essentially just trying to run `Running`.  Since there is no command named `Running` on your system you get command not found.  I imagine you want to `echo` or `printf` the result?

```
printf '%s\n' "$fs"
```

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion cleared that up for me. I went with echo, but I tried both and they worked. Have a good one!